# Fatal Error: Index out of range - UITableViewController - How to handle/catch this error Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an IOS application that uses a UiTablewView.  My app often crashes in the function below.  I would like some help in determining how i would catch this error ('Fatal Error: Index out of range') - determining when an index is out of range.  I am not sure how to code this.  Please could someone advise?

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
 IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "menuCell")
      cell.textLabel!.text = self.userFolderObjectArray[indexPath.section].arrayFolderNames[indexPath.row] // This is where I get the error

      ...
      return cell

 }
```

Comment: How are your `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods are configured?

Comment: You can’t catch/trap a *runtime error* in Swift — your app will simply be terminated. You need to check the *array bounds* if you want to detect this before it’s too late ;)

Comment: If you have returned userFolderObjectArray.count as numberOfSections and userFolderObjectArray[section].arrayFolderNames.count as numberOfRows, I would check whether my userFolderObjectArray is getting changed by some other thread when reload table is in process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the bounds of the arrays:

```
if indexPath.section < self.userFolderObjectArray.count,
    indexPath.row < self.userFolderObjectArray[indexPath.section].arrayFolderNames.count {
    // do your stuff
} else {
    print("index error")
}
```

What does your `numberOfRows` and `numberOfSections` look like?

Comment: I only have 2 sections.  The second section can have any number of rows.